# How to increase the replay value of presentation karaoke?

Tags: presentation, academic-life

In the context of an event for academics up to the postdoc stage, we organisers are considering hold a presentation karaoke (a.k.a. Powerpoint karaoke) for fun. The general idea is that you have to give a talk along a presentation you have never seen before.

The experiences amongst us organisers with such are mixed (or non-existent). A major concern (based on experience) is that the event gets redundant after one or two talks, and thus is not even worth the preparation – in short: presentation karaoke has a low [replay value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_value). Are there any strategies to avoid this? I am exclusively interested in ideas based on practical experience (yours or others’), not educated speculation. The [only guide](https://www.powerpointkaraoke.com/hosting-an-event) I could find does not address this issue.

Mind that our event is explicitly targeted at people who are experienced with talks in academia and ideally the slides reflect that, e.g., they should feature diagrams, plots, horrible equations, etc. (although no or little pure text). Thus, experience from similar events targetted at a business audience may not translate.

Comment: I'm trying hard to come up with the value proposition for this for, well, anybody. Other than showing that some (perhaps only one) people can give good talks about anything.

Comment: @JonCuster: Please see my edit.

Comment: What is the meaning of "replay value" in this context?

Comment: Might it be that the replay value is simply...limited? I can't speak to this specific game, but for improv in general I feel like short form improv is far easier and the key is more variety rather than refinement of any particular game/format.

Comment: @TerryLoring: Please see my edit.

Comment: I would just absolutely not do this except with a group quite explicitly interested in improv.